# How do you add a value to a float index of a dataframe for every other row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm recording data at 2000 Hz, which means every 0.5 milliseconds I have another data point.  But my recording software only records with 1 millisecond precision, so that means I have duplicate values in my dataframe index which uses type float.

So in order to fix the duplicates I want to add 0.005 to every other row of the index.  I tried this, but so far it doesn't work:

```
c = df.iloc[:,0] # select the first column of the dataframe
c = c.iloc[::-1]  # reverse order so that time is increasing not decreasing
pd.set_option('float_format', '{:f}'.format) # change the print output to show the decimals (instead of 15.55567E9)
i = c.index # get the index of c - the length is 20000
rp = np.matlib.repmat([0, 0.0005], 1, 10000) # create an array to repeat .0005 0 so that we can add 0.005 to every other row
df.set_index(c, i+rp).astype(float).applymap('{:,.4f}'.format) # set the index of c to i+rp - attempt to format to 4 decimals
print(c) # see if it worked
```

Expected output: (trimmed to save space - not showing all 20,000 rows)

```
1555677243.401000   4.569000
1555677243.401500   4.569000
1555677243.402000   4.571000
1555677243.402500   4.574000
1555677243.403000   4.574000
1555677243.403500   4.576000
1555677243.404000   4.577000
1555677243.404500   4.577000
1555677243.405000   4.577000
1555677243.405500   4.581000
1555677243.406000   4.581000
1555677243.406500   4.582000
1555677243.407000   4.581000
1555677243.407500   4.582000
1555677243.408000   4.580000
1555677243.408500   4.580000
1555677243.409000   4.582000
1555677243.409500   4.585000
1555677243.410000   4.585000
1555677243.410500   4.585000
```

Actual output: (notice duplicates in the index)

```
1555677243.401000   4.569000
1555677243.401000   4.569000
1555677243.402000   4.571000
1555677243.402000   4.574000
1555677243.403000   4.574000
1555677243.403000   4.576000
1555677243.404000   4.577000
1555677243.404000   4.577000
1555677243.405000   4.577000
1555677243.405000   4.581000
1555677243.406000   4.581000
1555677243.406000   4.582000
1555677243.407000   4.581000
1555677243.407000   4.582000
1555677243.408000   4.580000
1555677243.408000   4.580000
1555677243.409000   4.582000
1555677243.409000   4.585000
1555677243.410000   4.585000
1555677243.410000   4.585000
```

Comment: is there a specific reason not to just drop the duplicates since your machine has only a 1 millisecond precision anyway?

Comment: does the `Actual output:` you pasted above come from the last line says: `print(c) # see if it worked`?  if so, `c` still has old values from `c = c.iloc[::-1]`.

Comment: @AndyL. Why do you say that?  The index values are increasing whereas prior to the `c = c.iloc[::-1]` code they values were decreasing, so I think it did work.

Comment: @aguazul: oh, you misunderstood me. Yes, `c = c.iloc[::-1]` works fine. I mean different thing. In your code snippet, the last line is `print(c)`. Lines between `c = c.iloc[::-1]` and `print(c)` don't modify `c`. So, `print(c)` won't reflect changing by lines in between. I am asking to verify just in case of typo. I stumbled myself on this kind of typo in testing once ;)

Comment: @AndyL.  ooh, I see your point now - well I was trying to use the `set_index` attribute to change the index of `c`, so I thought that line was modifying `c`.  But I think I was using it wrong.  At any rate, Wen-Ben's answer worked for me, so problem solved.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC Data from gmds

```
df.index+=np.arange(len(df))%2*0.0005
df
        0
0.0000  0
0.0015  1
0.0020  2
0.0035  3
0.0040  4
0.0055  5
0.0060  6
0.0075  7
0.0080  8
0.0095  9
```

Comment: @aguazul yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                   'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})

df.iloc[1::2, 1] = df.iloc[1::2, :].eval('B + 0.005')

    A     B
0   1   1.000
1   2   2.005
2   3   3.000
3   4   4.005
4   5   5.000
5   6   6.005
6   7   7.000
7   8   8.005
8   9   9.000
```

Just have to make sure that your picking the correct column with the initial iloc. [1::2] is every other starting from index 1 (so 1,3 ect). You need to select all the columns in the second iloc due to eval only working with df's and not series. Then you can set that column to index as you did in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I dont have your dataframe, but you may think of creating a loop over even/odd indexes like. are you able to show us the original DF?

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:/random/d2', sep=',', header=None,names=['W1','W2'])
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
dfNew=pd.DataFrame(columns=['W1','W2'])
rows,clumns=df.shape
for index in range(rows):
    if(index %2==0):
        tempRow=['{0:.6f}'.format(df.iat[index,0]), df.iat[index,1]]
    else:
        tempRow=['{0:.6f}'.format(df.iat[index,0]+0.0005), df.iat[index,1]]
    dfNew.loc[len(dfNew)]=tempRow

print(df)
print('#############')
print(dfNew)
```

## data

```
1555677243.401000,4.569000
1555677243.401000,4.569000
1555677243.402000,4.571000
1555677243.402000,4.574000
1555677243.403000,4.574000
1555677243.403000,4.576000
1555677243.404000,4.577000
1555677243.404000,4.577000
1555677243.405000,4.577000
1555677243.405000,4.581000
1555677243.406000,4.581000
1555677243.406000,4.582000
1555677243.407000,4.581000
1555677243.407000,4.582000
1555677243.408000,4.580000
1555677243.408000,4.580000
1555677243.409000,4.582000
1555677243.409000,4.585000
1555677243.410000,4.585000
1555677243.410000,4.585000
```

## RESULT

```
                   W1     W2
0   1555677243.401000  4.569
1   1555677243.401500  4.569
2   1555677243.402000  4.571
3   1555677243.402500  4.574
4   1555677243.403000  4.574
5   1555677243.403500  4.576
6   1555677243.404000  4.577
7   1555677243.404500  4.577
8   1555677243.405000  4.577
9   1555677243.405500  4.581
10  1555677243.406000  4.581
11  1555677243.406500  4.582
12  1555677243.407000  4.581
13  1555677243.407500  4.582
14  1555677243.408000  4.580
15  1555677243.408500  4.580
16  1555677243.409000  4.582
17  1555677243.409500  4.585
18  1555677243.410000  4.585
19  1555677243.410500  4.585
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the index out, convert it to a `Series`, modify it, and put it back in (`Indexes` are immutable):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(10)), index=[x/ 1000 for x in range(10)])

new_index = df.index.to_series()
new_index[::2] += 0.0005
result = df.set_index(new_index)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
        0
0.0005  0
0.0010  1
0.0025  2
0.0030  3
0.0045  4
0.0050  5
0.0065  6
0.0070  7
0.0085  8
0.0090  9
```